# Customize email template for change password/email

Tags: magento2, admin, email, configuration, email-templates

I was trying to customize the emails but for change password or email I don't see where I have to apply my created email.

For forgot password for example, I go to (Stores > Configuration; Customers > Customer Configuration)

And at password options section I see "Forgot Email Template", so easy!
But I can't find change password or change password and email.

Any help?

Comment: Have you got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Magento didn't add a config setting to override the default template like they have for all other templates (I've looked everywhere for this as well). In this case you'll need to copy

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/change_email.html
```

to your custom theme

```
app/design/frontend/YourPackageName/YourThemeName/Magento_Customer/email/change_email.html
```

Make the changes to that file then upload and flush cache + static files. Hopefully they'll add it to the Customers config settings in the future.

Comment: How about if we want to edit the email subject? I can't find where to edit this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to go to Marketing --> Communications --> Email Templates:

[image: Magento 2 Menu Items]

From there, click:

[image: Add New Template]

Then, select the default template you want to edit and update in the system:
[image: List of Templates]

I hope this helps!

Comment: And there is no need to indicate on magento to use my created template?
Well this solution carries the translation issue... I created 2 templates of each functionality and then on one storeView I apply one template and for the other storeView the other template... in this case how I do that?

Comment: Yes, you'll want to save the template and indicate that this is the updated version taht you want to use for that specific template.  If you have multiple store views, you can set these on a per-store view basis.

Comment: Where I can set these on a per store view? this is actually my question. I can find easily the other templates, but this one don't.

Comment: In the drop down menu, you are able to select which theme you want the design to apply to.  For example, for Shipment Update, you can select the Shipment Update one for the entire site, or just the Shipment Update for the Magento/Luma theme. If you have multiple sites, you'll likely have multiple themes.

Comment: But where??? I don't know what are you saying? I just did what you said on the answer: http://i.imgur.com/O5jYnh8.png Now how I apply this template, where?

Comment: Using the drop down menu that I posted above, you can customize each template based on the THEME of the site. Not the actual site name.  Usually each site will have it's own theme, so that is how this is done.

Comment: I've already did that, but in my situation there is not THEME, look what I see: http://i.imgur.com/Z4PCiQ0.png. Now I have this new email template but it's not applied when I change email and password... I really don't understand

Comment: Not sure...  you may need to make sure that each store in your site has it's own theme.

Comment: yes I have: http://i.imgur.com/0QY22mo.png

Comment: Yes, the challenge is that all of your different sites have the same theme name, "Adella."  To make this work better, you might want to rename each theme so you can keep track of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default email in Stores-Configuration in Customers tab select Customer Configuration- Password Option you will find Forgot Email Template. Uncheck Use system value and you can select your own template that you created on Marketing - Email Templates