# Magento2.3.1 How to add customer grid mass action link reset forget password and custom reset forget email sent to customer

Tags: magento2, customer, adminhtml, magento2.3.1, massaction

I am using `Magneto 2.3.1` and how to add customer `mass-action` inside link add reset forget password and when select customer sent to email for customer, but email not use in default Magento our custom email assign and set it.

If this type of work and idea reply me...

Comment: can you elaborate more.

Comment: please check this one - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160823/customize-email-template-for-change-password-email

Comment: but i need to not this one i need custom email template call in customer mass action inside resetpassowrd click than email sent it so how to possible thatif you see in admin side like subscriber link shows in mass inside same it work on my reset forgot password

Comment: check with my answer to add foreach in my code for emails.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code in controller :

```
public function __construct(
    Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement,
) {
    $this->session = $customerSession;
    $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function sendCustomMail()
{

            $email = 'customermail@example.com'; // loop your email.


            try {
                $this->customerAccountManagement->initiatePasswordReset(
                    $email,
                    AccountManagement::EMAIL_RESET
                );
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                // Do nothing, we don't want anyone to use this action to determine which email accounts are registered.
            } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                    $exception,
                    __('We\'re unable to send the password reset email.')
                );
            }
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($this->getSuccessMessage($email));
}
```